# Angular Firebase: Get dynamic data from Firebase for dropdown menu

Tags: node.js

I am doing a simple single page web application using Firebase and Angular for the first time.

I have a current working form which takes some user input (time, some string input etc.) and then stores it in the database (it is displayed then on the home screen). This is working fine. I want to modify this form to include a drop down menu. This drop down menu needs to be populated with data from the Firebase database, namely, the list of all users (identified by the emails they signed up with) in the database. (I've already linked to the database, there is some other code which interacts with it successfully already). I am unsure of the easiest way to achieve this. I followed this tutorial here - the code is not throwing any compile errors, but my drop down menu is not populated with any data.

I followed this guide here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czN9w5FbjSc

Here is my code. My form HTML:

```
<label for="tasktime">Completion Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="tasktime" name="tasktime" formControlName="completion" required style="width: 100%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;"><br><br>

      <br><br>

      <label for="users" class="form-label">users</label>
      <select id = "users" name = "users" class="form-select" ngModel>
      <option *ngFor="let i of users" [ngValue]="i.email">{{i.id}}</option>
      ></select>
      <br><br>
```

I have created a service which contains a method to get the data from Firebase.

```
getAll(): Observable<any[]>{
   return this.db.list<any>("/users")
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(x => x.map((y:any) => ({...y.payload.val(), id: y.payload.key})))
    )
  }
```

The component module begins:

```
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {

  users: any;
```

and thereafter I have have defined the Constructor and various methods. The getAll() method is then referenced in the ngOnInit (ignore the other ones for now)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allKeys = [];
    this.allValues = [];
    this.getTasks();
    this.userService.getAll().subscribe(i => this.users = i);
  }
```

I hope this question is clear. I am new to this. If this isn't clear enough, maybe someone can recommend a more straightforward way of dynamically populating a drop down menu with data from my Firebase.

Thank you in advance!